# Play Framework EBean fetch Object with Relations

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

I am trying to fetch a `Question` with all its `Answers`

**Question**

```
@Entity
public class Question extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Constraints.Required
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>(4);
  ...
}
```

**Answer**

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends Model{
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  public Question question;
  ...
}
```

**Query**

```
public static Result getQuestion() {
    return ok(
        Json.toJson(Question.find
        .fetch("answers")
        .orderBy("question.id")
        .setMaxRows(1)
        .findList()
        .get(0)
        )
    );
}
```

**`fetch("answers")` throws a `Nullpointerexception`.**

Database tables `question` and `answer` are consistent. Table `answer` includes the correct foreign keys to the `question` table.

**Stacktrace**

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.getBeanDescriptor(BeanDescriptor.java:1411) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.OrmQueryDetail.setDefaultSelectClause(OrmQueryDetail.java:414) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.setDefaultSelectClause(DefaultOrmQuery.java:842) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQueryRequest(DefaultServer.java:1105) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQueryRequest(DefaultServer.java:1093) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was this line in the `Question` class:

```
public ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>(4);
```

In Play Framework, must **use the List Interface** instead of the implementation:

```
public List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the "answer" which is not null

This should work

```
Question.find.fetch("answers").where().isNotNull("answers");
```

This might work

```
Question.find.fetch("answers").where().ne("answers.id", null);
```